# Kendo DropDownListFor in EditorTemplate

Tags: dynamic, kendo-ui, grid

I am creating a Dynamic Kendo Grid using `GridBoundColumnBuilder()`.

I loop through all of the controls on the previous page to create the grid.
For example with `myTextbox()`, `myCheckbox()`, etc.

These create columns in the grid. I have all of the columns creating and populating with data.

My issue is with the `Dropdownlist` and the `Multiselect` list, they populate with data but do not display the correct data when the grid is created.
The dropdown list displays the value, not the text of the previous control:

```
1 = My
2 = Data
```

The `Dropdownlist` will display `1` instead of `My`. And, the `Multiselect` only displays `[object Object]`.

When you click on either of the controls in the grid it switches to show the proper text, but loses it when you click off.

Any ideas of what I am doing wrong?

```
foreach (ControlBase control in flatColumns)
 {
      GridBoundColumnBuilder<dynamic> thisColumn;
      if (control.Lookups != null && control.Lookups.Any())
           {
                if (!control.IsMultiSelect){
                     thisColumn = column.Bound(control.ControlType, control.ColumnName).Title(control.Description);
                            thisColumn.EditorTemplateName("DropDownList");
                            thisColumn.Width(250);
                  }
                   else
                   {
                        thisColumn = column.Bound(control.ControlType, control.ColumnName).Title(control.Description);
                            thisColumn.EditorTemplateName("MultiDropDownList");
                            thisColumn.Width(250);
                    }

     }
}

Dropdown Template
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "form-control" })
    .BindTo((IEnumerable) ViewData[currentColumn + "List"])
        .DataTextField("Text")
        .DataValueField("Value")
        .ValuePrimitive(true)
                .Text("Value")

Multiselect Templage

@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor(m => m)
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "form-control" })

                        .BindTo((IEnumerable)ViewData[currentColumn + "List"])
                        .DataTextField("Text")
                        .DataValueField("Value")
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the .Text to display the Text rather than the Value?

```
    .DataTextField("Text")
    .DataValueField("Value")
    .ValuePrimitive(true)
            .Text("Text")
```